# Default Constructor with Empty Brackets C++ Error

Tags: c++, templates, definition

I do not know why it crashes when I create class Vector. Please Help. In this program I want to add any type of elements into an array. I use eclipse with Cross gcc, Ubuntu

```
template<typename T>
class Vector{
    public:
        Vector();
        void add(const T&);
    private:
        T *elem;
        int cap;
        int len;
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(){
    len = 0;
    cap = 30;
    elem = new T[cap];
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::(const T& m){
    elem[len] = m;
    len ++;
}

// Here I create Vector v, if I put Vector<int> v() I don't get error
Vector<int> v; //error "undefined reference to `Vector<int>::Vector()"
v.add(21); //error
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Brian  It is very funny that you do not use "very interesting features". I can not even imagine this.:)

Comment: The compiler needs visibility of the template definitions (both the `Vector<T>` class AND its member functions) at the point where you intend to use `Vector<T>`.    Separate compilation and templates do not play together well.      Place the definition of member functions in the header that declares the class, and make sure you `#include` that header in code which needs to use the `Vector` template.   [This isn't a complete answer].

Comment: "i don't get error" - you certainly would get error if you still had `v.add(21)` following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place member function definitions (including constructor definitions) in the same header where the template class is defined.

As for this statement

```
// here i create Vector v, if i put Vector<int> v() i don't get error
Vector<int> v();
```

then it is a function declaration that has return type `Vector<int>` and does not have parameters. It is not a definition of an object of type `Vector<int>`.